# Coverity scan - VS 2019 c++ project

Tags: c++, coverity

I am trying to scan my visual studio c++ project using coverity.
Using command line:

1. cov-configure --msvc
2. cov-build --dir idir --fs-capture-search [enter the \bin directory where files are output] msbuild.exe projectname.sln

This build is succeeded but 0 errors and 0 warnings which should not be right.

Any thoughts how I can approach this?